# Angular 2 Http timeout

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I have a problem posting a custom error message on HTTP timeout.

Here is the simple example:

```
return this._http.get(url).timeout(5000, new Error("Error message"));
```

I saw that everybody uses **new Error("Error message")** but I'm getting the error:

> Error function expects type Scheduler. I'm getting this error:
>   Argument of type 'Error' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Scheduler'. Property 'SchedulerAction' is missing in type 'Error'

Answer (score 9):

In rxjs 4, it was possible to customise the error message that way. However, in latest versions of rxjs 5, `timeout` only accepts two arguments:

- due: number | Date
- scheduler: IScheduler (this is to manage how the Observable processes the timeout)

If you want to customise your error, you may try something like:

```
return this._http.get(url)
 .timeout(5000)
 .catch(err => {

   if (err.name !== "TimeoutError") {
      return Observable.throw("Timeout has occurred");
   }

   return Observable.throw(err);

});
```

Comment: Why has a timeout occurred when the name of the error is NOT "TimeoutError"

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do that with `timeoutWith`:

```
return this._http.get(url).timeoutWith(5000, Observable.throw(new Error("Error message")));
```

Answer (score 0):

As of version rc.5, timeout no longer accepts the errorToSend argument.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-rc5-2016-12-07

Answer (score 0):

You can use (rxjs 6.6.3)

```
import { timeoutWith } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { throwError } from 'rxjs'
// ...
return this.http.get(url).pipe(timeoutWith(5000, throwError(new Error("Error message"))))
// ...
```