# angular2 http.post to a turned off server => return error on Android BUT NOT ON IOS

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic2, angular2-http

I am using Angular 2, Ionic 2.

I shut down the server my app sends its request to, in order to check how the offline mode is managed.

I have made a Custom HTTP Service for my project based on `import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, Request } from '@angular/http'`. It includes a 'function sendRequest':

```
public sendRequest = (data):Observable<Response> => {
    // console.log("CustomHttpService->sendRequest() starts");
    let headersToUse = new Headers();
    headersToUse.append("Content-type",'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    data = this.jsonToURLEncoded(data);
    let options = { headers:headersToUse };
    return this.http.post(this.url, data, options).map(
    (res:Response)=>{
        return res.json();
    }
    ).catch(
            this.handleErrorObservable
        );
  }
```

And the 'function handleErrorObservable':

```
private handleErrorObsevable (error:Response|any){
    console.log("handleError error.message " + error.message);
    console.log("handleError error " + error);
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
}
```

In Android it works, after a certain time I get in the log:

> handleError error Response with status 0 for URL: null

**But on IOS the error never arrives, like if there was no time out set. Any tips?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a custom timeout setting on the observable like [in that SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465687/angular-2-http-timeout), in my function. It looks like that now:

```
public sendRequest = (data):Observable<Response> | Observable<any> => {
// console.log("CustomHttpService->sendRequest() starts");

    let headersToUse = new Headers();
    headersToUse.append("Content-type",'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    data = this.jsonToURLEncoded(data);

    let options = { headers:headersToUse };

    return this.http.post(this.url, data, options).timeoutWith(CustomHttpService.TIMEOUT_DELAY,Observable.throw(new Error(CustomHttpService.ERROR_REQ_HTTP))).map(
        (res:Response)=>{
            return res.json();
        }
    )
    .catch(this.handleErrorObservable)
}

private handleErrorObservable (error:Response|any){
    console.error(CustomHttpService.CLASS_TAG + " handlerErrorObservable: error.message " + error.message);

    return Observable.throw(error.message);

}
```

Also it requires to add on the top of the class some specific import to use the functions `timeoutWith` and `Observable.throw`:
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeoutWith` and `import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw` like it is explained in the [official Angular2 doc](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#import-rxjs-operators).

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to use this fomart of @angular/http to handle errors and it works throughout.

```
this.http.post(url, data)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe((data) => {
      // Use returned data
     },
     (err) => {
            // Handle the error here
          });
```

The `(err)` part helps handle all network related errors even when server is offline. Hope this helps.

Comment: It gives the same result as before. The error shows in Android but not on IOS.

Comment: Did you try serving the app in safari browser to see if the http error handling was working

Comment: I did the `ionic serve` test in SAFARI, I get the same issue. It does show a warning message in the console that the request has gone on time out but that message is independent from my code. It does not trigger the `.catch(this.handleErrorObservable)` and doen't show the error thru the `console.log(...)`. At least the error is consistent thru Apple browsers.